# Stored Procedure does not return any result

Tags: java, oracle

I am passing a collection of Array to a Stored procedure.Below is the code for Stored procedure.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE R5_QA_126.GIVE_ME_AN_ARRAY( p_list  in TEST_LIST, p_recordset OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
AS
BEGIN
DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE(100);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Hi reached before begin');
 OPEN p_recordset FOR
  SELECT words, count
  FROM documents_token
  where words in (select word from table(p_list));
    EXCEPTION
     WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
       NULL;
     WHEN OTHERS THEN
       -- Consider logging the error and then re-raise
       RAISE;
END GIVE_ME_AN_ARRAY;
/
```

I have a type declared as below.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TESTREC AS OBJECT
(
  word VARCHAR2(500)
)
/
```

and table declared as below.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TEST_LIST
AS TABLE OF TESTREC
/
```

I am having issue when i try to make a call to Stored procedure.
ps.execute(); from my java code. 
It does not return any result.

Below is what i am setting for the call to array.

```
OracleCallableStatement ps = (OracleCallableStatement) conn
                    .prepareCall("{call GIVE_ME_AN_ARRAY(?,?)}");
            ps.setARRAY(1, array_to_pass);
            ps.registerOutParameter(2, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
```

Please let me know whats wrong i am doing here.
Also i am setting ArrayDescriptor and StructDescriptor properly

Comment: Does the stored procedure return a result set when you call it from PL/SQL with identical parameter values?

Comment: You should log the value of the array and parameters passed to the procedure to be sure that they are what you think they are. Logging to a file or a table via autonomous_transaction.